# R Program, Function doesn't recognize input string of column name

Tags: r, function, variables

I have function in R to get mean of anything, which is any column name of dataframe

```
mean_anything <- function(directory, anything){
  files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  seethis <- lapply(files_full, read.csv)
  output <- do.call(rbind, seethis)
  mean(output$anything, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

If I invoke `mean_anything("diet_data", "Age")` I get

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(output$anything, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

However, if I replace

```
mean(output$anything, na.rm=TRUE)
```

with

```
mean(output$Age, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Then the function will output `[1] 36.4`

I tried using single and double quotes around `anything`, I tried output[anything], how to fix?

#### dput(output)

```
structure(list(Patient.Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L), .Label = c("Andy", "David", "John", "Mike", "Steve"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
    35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
    35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
    35L, 35L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
    22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
    22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 40L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 
    55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 
    55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L), Weight = c(140L, 
    140L, 140L, 139L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 
    138L, 137L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 139L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 210L, 
    209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 208L, 208L, 208L, 208L, 
    208L, 208L, 207L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 205L, 205L, 205L, 205L, 
    204L, 204L, 204L, 203L, 203L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 201L, 175L, 
    175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 
    175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 177L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 189L, 
    189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 190L, 
    190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 192L, 192L, 
    192L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 225L, 225L, 225L, 224L, 224L, 
    224L, 223L, 223L, 223L, 223L, 223L, 222L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 
    220L, 220L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 218L, 217L, 217L, 217L, 216L, 
    215L, 215L, 214L, 214L, 214L), Day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
    23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L)), .Names = c("Patient.Name", "Age", "Weight", 
"Day"), row.names = c(NA, 150L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @akrun I just solved it, i.e. `mean(output[,anything], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Why the downvote people?

Comment: This question, while a very common issue, is enough of a "beginner" issue that some on SO may think that you could have solved this with more research. I wouldn't worry too much; your question itself is well written. If you continue to ask questions that are this clearly written, you should be fine going forward. I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

```
mean(output[,anything], na.rm=TRUE)
```

i.e.

```
mean_anything <- function(directory, anything){
  files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  seethis <- lapply(files_full, read.csv)
  output <- do.call(rbind, seethis)
  mean(output[,anything], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Where `anything` is any column in the dataframe